# Hide all desktop icons under Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, icons, osx-snow-leopard, desktop

I am looking for a way to show/hide desktop icons programmatically in objective-c under Mac OS X.

Do you have any idea on how I can achieve this?

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

The Finder has a hidden preference for this. Set the value of `CreateDesktop` under `com.apple.finder` to `kCFBooleanFalse`, then kill the Finder. To put the desktop icons back, delete the `CreateDesktop` preference and kill the Finder again.

Of course, this isn't a supported API feature; it could go away at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this short of actually moving the items on and off the desktop, or patching the Finder, neither of which is a particularly good idea.

Another option is to place a window over the top of the icon you're trying to hide.  See my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222769/).