# show desktop/hide all windows under Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, desktop

I am trying to create an application which show the desktop / hide all application even the finder.

Do you have any idea to achieve this?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: @zoul: Just because they're asked by the same person in a short span of time about a similar topic doesn't mean they're duplicates in terms of content.

Comment: Note that if you hide the Finder and all other apps such that only the Desktop is visible, acutally interacting the the Desktop will unhide the Finder such that any windows which may have been open (and hidden) will reappear.

Comment: @BoltClock: Sorry, missed the difference between windows and icons :)

Answer (score 2):

When you hide the Finder, you don't hide the icons on the desktop.  If you're fine with that, then use [`-[NSWorkspace hideOtherApplications]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-hideOtherApplications).

Otherwise you'll need to draw your own window over the top of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are really trying to do.  Have a look at the [Apple docs on kiosk mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html) to see if they help.

Comment: I want to hide all windows to see the desktop

Comment: @AP: did you check out the link?  I'm pretty sure that if you hide all the other applications and use the method in the link I posted to get rid of the menu bar, it'll do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using applescript to set the current application to find then executing the `[NSWorkspace hideOtherApplications]`.

```
Activate Application "Finder"
```

Pretty much all the additional code you need. Fairly simple.