# Hide/Show Mac OS X desktop hard disk icons programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, finder

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222751/hide-all-desktop-icons-under-mac-os), but not identical. I do not want to know how to toggle *all* icons on the desktop, but rather how to modify the finder settings explained [here](http://lifehacker.com/399983/remove-your-macs-hard-drive-from-the-desktop), namely "Show these items on the desktop: Hard disks". Is there a way to do that using Cocoa?

[image]

Comment: Try browsing the Finder preferences.  Run `defaults read com.apple.Finder` in the terminal.  You can change the corresponding preferences easy enough using the NSUserDefaults API.

Comment: @DietrichEpp If you'd post your comment as an answer I could accept it :)

Comment: It wasn't really a complete answer, it was just a pointer to some docs and further reading.  If you've figured the whole thing out, feel free to write up an answer and accept it.