# Hide desktop icons using Applescript in Mac app

Tags: swift, macos, applescript

I've this following applescript to hide desktop icons that works fine when it run it standalone.

```
on run
   do shell script "chflags hidden ~/Desktop/*"
end run
```

Goal: Hide desktop icons by tapping a button from a mac app, so I wrote the applescript code in mac app using swift.

```
func hideDesktopIcons() {
        
        let source = """
        on run
            do shell script "chflags hidden ~/Desktop/*"
        end run
        """

        let script = NSAppleScript(source: source)!
        var error: NSDictionary?
        script.executeAndReturnError(&error)
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Also I've made sure that the following keys are set
[image: 1]

[image]

Result:

```
{
    NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = "Focus";
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "chflags: /Users/deepu/Library/Containers/com.deepu.Focus/Data/Desktop/*: No such file or directory";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "chflags: /Users/deepu/Library/Containers/com.deepu.Focus/Data/Desktop/*: No such file or directory";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = 1;
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {3, 53}";
}
```

I've read this but doesn't seem to be working at all [Hide all desktop icons under Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222751/hide-all-desktop-icons-under-mac-os?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: (1) You are sandboxed. (2) If you just want to give a shell command, why pass thru AppleScript at all?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to hide icons in applescript, thus picked up shell command in applescript.

Comment: You're answering backwards. Try to hear what I'm saying. If you know how to hide icons using the shell, you don't need AppleScript in the first place. Just throw the AppleScript stuff away and talk to the shell directly (using Process). — But you will _still_ need to be nonsandboxed in order to do this.